# Rephrase the Sentence

Tags: phrases, american-english

I have a picture that I am trying to give a caption to. Following is what I have come up with, but it just not sounding right.

It's picture of San Francisco downtown in the background and bay in the foreground.

`So, your words are as tall as those Skylines, but your actions are as low as that water.`

Is there a better way to phrase that?

Comment: That's not bad.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the sentence and the image, besides "lot of talk, but very little action" ?

Comment: That's pretty much it. Im trying to reflect that photograph in words, so when a reader sees the picture and reads the caption, they both sync.

Comment: I think it sounds odd because people don't use 'low' to describe action.  You could substitute motivation and it may sound more natural as in: your **effort** is as low as the water.

Comment: I think of "skyline" as singular. Plural sounds wrong in this scenario.

Comment: @MoA: Are you aware that your caption example is an insult to the reader?

Comment: @MarkHubbard I see what you mean, but that's not my intention. The readers know who they are, and  it's up to their discretion how they take it..

Answer (score 0):

This may change what you were trying to say a little but what about this:

> "So, your words are as tall as those Skylines, but your conviction
>   recedes like the tide."

Comment: Yea it does changes what I am trying to say. I also like @Minnow's idea, to replace efforts with actions.

Comment: I agree with @Minnow as well, but I think they meant replace action with effort